# Java unzip file error. Compression type not supported

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, zip

I have a unzip file exception at Java. The zipped file is too large. Size is 550 MB.

I have tried too many libraries for this error. But none of them solved it.
At last, I used 'net.lingala.zip4j.core' library.

```
    import net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile;

    public static void unzip(String source, String destination){
        try {
            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(source);
            zipFile.extractAll(destination);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: From your title it seems that the problem is the compression itself. Maybe The algorithms is not supported by zip4j. Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238537/zip4j-compression-type-not-supported-exception-android  Maybe if you create this zip file you can change the compression algorithm

Comment: Even when not unzipping, you can get access to the meta data on the entries, like compression method and inspect that. Maybe it is something esoteric like .bz2 / jpeg2000 or you might get the raw data by extracting the compressed data.

Comment: So what happens, when you don’t use a 3rd party library, but just Java’s builtin facility?

Comment: When I didn't use third party libs, the same error again.